# how to set date_default_timezone_set('UTC') to be UTC plus five

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I need to set time zone to be UTC-5 without using countries

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
```

Comment: You can set it to GMT+5 with 'Etc/GMT+5' But I do not understand why not a country?

Comment: Sorry. You should use: 'Etc/GMT-5'  This will actually give GMT+5!!! It's reversed.

Comment: UTC-5 is for New York and New York has Daylight saving in summer so I don't want to be enrolled in